# Amount of paragraphs for a chapter?

Tags: novel

Is there an appropriate amount of paragraphs to a chapter, I have honestly been trying to compact some techniques in my head, I have just been curious if there is an amount of paragraphs when i know to stop and slow don the particular chapter.

Answer (score 0):

The way i found out was just writing the first chapter. This is my first pattern.

After, you will look furthermore things, like the paragraph size itself, its pace, their communication...

You'll probably get some huge chapther forward, but will find ways to break on two.